# What does `!name` mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What does `!varName` mean?

I tried it out by doing the following:

```
var varName = "string"
console.log(!varName)
```

Console printed "false". What does this mean?

Comment: This means that the `type` of ```String``` is not equal to true. :) 


check out these docs on falsy values https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly I thought since the string is not empty, it should be true, no?

Comment: @apricotzlover `!` is negation. When a string is not empty,  it is considered as a truthful value, so when cast into boolean, the javascript interpreter will look it as `!"string"` -> `!true` -> `false`.

Comment: @JamiePhan that was so silly of me, thanks